# Tab não altera quando mudo de pagina

Tags: ionic, ionic3

Estou em uma pagina e quando click em um botão chamo um evento, quero que ele chame outra tela, eles esta chamando porem as tabs não esta se alterando, continua na mesma da que esta no botão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código que estou usando para chamar a pagina.

```
this.navCtrl.setPages([
        { page: AboutPage }
      ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passe o index da tab que ira mudar como parâmetro:

```
this.navCtrl.setPages([{page: AboutPage, tabIndex: 2}]);
```

Dai no destino, pegue o parâmetro tabIndex e mude a aba:

```
this.nav.parent.select(tabIndex);
```